# How to finish this complicated query inside two while loops

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a music player, where a song can be added to a playlist. However, if the song has *already* been added to the playlist, I want to hide *that* playlist for that *particular* song. I say *that* because you can have more than one playlist and one song can be in multiple playlists.

**Code**

```
<?php
      
      $shuffle = $_GET["shuffle"];
    
        $songsContent = $db->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_band='$band' && album_name='$album'");
         
      $numSongsContent = $songsContent->num_rows;
      
      $number = 0;
      
      while($fetch_songs = mysqli_fetch_array($songsContent)) {
        $number++;
        $song_path = $fetch_songs["song_path"];
        $song_title = $fetch_songs["song_title"];
        $song_band = $fetch_songs["song_band"];
        echo "<div class='songs' path='Music/$song_band/$song_path.mp3' number='$number' total='$numSongsContent'> $song_title <div id='song_playlist'> <i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
 Add to Playlist <div id='song_playlist_popup'>";
 
 
 $getPlaylists = $db->query("SELECT * FROM playlists");
 
 
 while($fetch_playlists = mysqli_fetch_array($getPlaylists)) {
    $playlist_name = $fetch_playlists["playlist_name"];
```

This is the part of the code that I'm having difficulty with. In this part, this is where the playlists are outputted. I'm trying to control this output by a conditional statement. But, the data seems to completely ignore the condition:

```
 $checkDuplicates = $db->query("SELECT * FROM playlist_songs WHERE playlist_name='$playlist_name' AND song_name='$song_title'");
    $numDuplicates = $checkDuplicates->num_rows;
    
    if($numDuplicates == 0) {
      echo "<div id='playlist_name'> <span song='$song_title'> $playlist_name </span> </div>";
    }
    
 }
 
 echo  "<div id='playlist_name2'> <span id='playlist_input_errors'></span> <input id='playlist_input' placeholder='Create new Playlist' song='$song_title'> </div> </div> </div> </div>";

      }
      
      ?>
```

How do I fix this query to only allow playlists that haven't been added to a song? Thanks...

**EDIT**

Screenshot of *Playlist Songs* db

[image: Playlist Songs]

Screenshot of *Playlists* db

[image: Playlists]

I'm not sure how I can better organize my code. Trust me, you don't want to see all my code. It doesn't relate to this problem and only make things more confusing...

**EDIT @DestinatioN**

This is my current code. Did I do something wrong? Now, the playlists aren't displaying at all. I've cleared the counts of playlist_songs...

```
 <?php
      
      $shuffle = $_GET["shuffle"];
    
        $songsContent = $db->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_band='$band' && album_name='$album'");
         
      $numSongsContent = $songsContent->num_rows;
      
      $number = 0;
      
      while($fetch_songs = mysqli_fetch_array($songsContent)) {
        $number++;
        $song_path = $fetch_songs["song_path"];
        $song_title = $fetch_songs["song_title"];
        $song_band = $fetch_songs["song_band"];
        echo "<div class='songs' path='Music/$song_band/$song_path.mp3' number='$number' total='$numSongsContent'> $song_title <div id='song_playlist'> <i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
 Add to Playlist <div id='song_playlist_popup'>";
 
 
$getPlaylists = $db->query("SELECT *
FROM playlists pl
LEFT JOIN playlist_songs pls ON pl.playlist_name = pls.playlist_name
WHERE song_name != song_name='$song_title'");
 
 
 while($fetch_playlists = mysqli_fetch_array($getPlaylists)) {
    $playlist_name = $fetch_playlists["playlist_name"];
    
      echo "<div id='playlist_name'> <span song='$song_title'> $playlist_name </span> </div>";
    
 }
 
 echo  "<div id='playlist_name2'> <span id='playlist_input_errors'></span> <input id='playlist_input' placeholder='Create new Playlist' song='$song_title'> </div> </div> </div> </div>";

      }
      
      ?>
```

Comment: By making it less complicate and more efficient by eliminating the while loops.

query -> loop through results -> query based on previous result can 99.9% of the times be replaced by a join.

Comment: @e4c5 I can try, this is my first year programming. I'm still learning...

Comment: there are some excellent tutorials on SQL joins. Looks like you are going to need a three table join. If that feels two intimidating first try joinging playlists and playlist_songs

Comment: @e4c5 Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: would you provide your table structure and more format your code a bit?

Comment: @e4c5 Edited answer...

Comment: @FaceCode you could dump your database tables and a small part of the data and then copy paste it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ and then share the link with us

Comment: exactly @caramba I was just about to say one should never post screenshots of the tables, they are practically useless. And your code still needs formatting. You are doing yourself a big favour by learning to format your code.

Answer (score 1):

With `$getPlaylists` you select all existing Playlists and inside your second `while` loop you check for duplicated entrys.
Why not do it in `$getPlaylists` by using a mix of `$getPlaylists` and `$checkDuplicates`.
Like others said in the comments you can join your tables by modifying your query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM playlists pl
LEFT JOIN playlist_songs pls ON pl.playlist_name = pls.playlist_name
WHERE song_name != song_name='$song_title'
```

With this query you should get every Playlist which hasn't an entry with the `$song_title` in `playlist_songs` so you don't need to check for duplicates with `$checkDuplicates` anymore.

---

A little advice at the end. I really recommend you to use ID's as foreign keys in your database because names aren't always unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are many comments about your code.

1. Try to make fewer requests to the database. Do not try to request all data in one query, but definitely do not make a separate request per each line in the table.
2. If some data does not change, request it once. For example, there is no need to request a list of playlist for each song. It is enough to request it once.
3. Use ID as foreign keys. Learn about database indexes and foreign keys.
4. Your task can be solved by doing the following:

   - Make tables something like this: songs (song_id, name, any other data...); playlists (playlist_id, name, any other data...); playlist_songs (id, playlist_id, song_id)
   - Make one request per each table;
   - iterate over table playlist_songs and make multidimensional array `$songsPlaylists = array (song_id => array(playlist_id, playlist_id, ...))`
   - output songs, for each song iterate over playlists, if not `in_array(playlist_id, $songsPlaylists[song_id])`, output the playlist.
5. Do not forget to learn about security (SQL injections, OWASP Top 10, etc).

Good luck in learning!